# How to go to a specific tab with Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm creating a Firefox Extension. It opens a new tab and then closes it a moment later. When the new tab closes, I want to go back to the original tab I was on, NOT the rightmost tab. This is what I have so far and it always goes to the rightmost.

```
function openNewTab(tabs) {
    let tab = tabs[0]; 
    browser.tabs.create({"url": tab.url});
}

function closeTab(tabs) {
    let tab = tabs[0];
    browser.tabs.remove(tab.id);    
}

function onError(err){
    console.error(err);
}

function openAndClose() {
    var mytab = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}).then(openNewTab, onError);

    setTimeout(function () {
        var closeIt = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}).then(closeTab, onError); 
    }, 1000);   
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openAndClose);
```

Given a tab id, or tab index, how do I activate, or go to that specific tab?

Answer (score 0):

You want the window & tab update functions.  You can disregard focusing the window as long as you keep focus of the window when you create your new tab.  (As currently shown in your code sample)

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/update
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update

  ```
  browser.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    for (var i=tabs.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
      if (tabs[i].id == myTabID) {
          browser.windows.update(tabs[i].windowId, {focused: true});       //focus window
          browser.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {active: true});       //focus tab
        break;
      }
    }
  });
  ```